# Is there a more efficient way to oversample data than random.sample()?

Tags: random, classification, oversampling, imbalanced-data

I got a big unbalanced classification problem and want to address this issue by oversampling the minor classes. (N(class 1) = 8,5mio, N(class n) = 3000)

For that purpose I want to get 100.000 sample for each of the n classes by

```
data_oversampled = []
for data_class_filtered in data:
    data_oversampled.append(data_class_filtered.sample(n=20000, replace=True))
```

where `data` is a list of class specific DataFrames and `len(data)=10`, `data.shape=(9448788,97)`

That works as expected but unfortunately takes literally forever. Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing?

Comment: what do you mean by "literally forever"?  what's `len(data)` and what shapes are the dataframes? from a stats PoV: replicating the same values ~33 times seems like it would quickly bias estimates.  maybe you could use a model that handles this more directly?

Comment: I added some information about the data `len(data)=10`, `data.shape=(9448788,97)`. Do you know a rule of thumb of whats a adivseable dimension of oversampling?
Takes for hours at least.

Comment: that's a lot of data, are you sure your computer isn't swapping?  9.5M*97 `float64`s takes ~7GB, and other data types could be a lot more!  swapping can make things a million times slower, which randomly sampling from a dataframe would tend to do

Comment: you've not given enough detail for me to comment on the stats.  maybe post another question about it specifically, probably to https://stats.stackexchange.com